# How to make screen reader announces “1of7”/“2of7” kind of information?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I understand that by using the role="treeitem" plus aria-setsize and aria-posinset you can make the screen reader announces the position of an item in a set such as "1 of 7" or "2 of 7".

Is there a way to do the same thing for other groups such as menu bar, or tab strip? We certainly don't want to enforce the "treeitem" role just to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a menu bar, a logical structure to use would be an unordered list `<ul>`

A screenreader encountering this list would inform the user that a list of x items was present e.g. "list of 7 items", but it wouldn't inform the user of the ordinal position of each link item, so it would it would read out "Bullet: link, Bullet: blah" depending on the list contents.

If it is important for the user to be aware of the step number e.g. a list of sequential instructions, then using an ordered list would be more appropriate e.g.

```
<ol>
<li>Start your browser</li>
<li>Navigate to Stackoverflow</li>
</ol>
```

Using CSS, you could remove the numbers, or change the formatting of the ordered list. Removing the numbers would make no different to how a screenreader read out the list, so they would still hear 1, 2, 3 etc.